# Как отправить в телеграм канал пост с картинкой?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить пост в мой теллеграм канал через бота (он админ в моём канале).
Использую ноду 18. npm пакет node-telegram-bot-api.
Если отправляю просто текст, то нормально отправляется.
Если прикрепляю картинку, то ничего не отправляет, не могу понять почему.

**Код отправки просто текстового поста (норм отправляет):**

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
let OSHIBKA = '';
const bot = new TelegramBot('653*****скрыл****F_JQ');
const text = 
` просто текстовый текст`;
bot.sendMessage('@СКРЫЛ', text, {parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  OSHIBKA = err.toString();
});
```

**Код отправки с картинкой (ничего не отправляет):**

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const fs = require('fs-extra'); // Используем fs-extra
let OSHIBKA = '';
const bot = new TelegramBot('653*****скрыл****F_JQ');
const text =
` просто текстовый текст`;
const photoPath = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\скрипт\\kartinka_preview.jpg';
const photo = fs.createReadStream(photoPath);

bot.sendPhoto('@СКРЫЛ', photo, {caption: text, parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    OSHIBKA = err.toString();
  });
```

Comment: вопрос решил сам. всем спасибо

Comment: Стоит опубликовать ответ, если нашлось решение, это может помочь другим пользователям как вы. В противном случае ваш вопрос закроют.